# how to run a part of shell script with root user

Tags: bash

I have a part of my shell script that runs under **rsadmin user**. This part creates a file, which I want to transfer to another server through root user as the root user can do anything (both servers have SSH key setting implemented).

I tried various options provided on forums but nothing has worked till now, not sure if it is achievable but looking at so many responses to other posts, it seems it is.

I am doing something like below in my shell script (which runs under rsadmin user) on server 1.

```
exec sudo u - root /bin/ bash << EOF
scp <file name with path on server_1> root@server_2:<some_path>
EOF
```

I have also tried like below in the shell script on server 1 (which runs under rsadmin user)

```
sudo su - root "scp <file name with path on server_1> root@server_2:<some_path>"
```

Nothing has worked yet. Though when I run this command directly from command prompt of server_1 (out of shell script) as root user, it works.

Comment: This is usually done via the shell command line: `sudo /bin/bash -c 'your commands'`. But take care of escaping quotes properly, it's tricky. You can try your input redirect approach, with another flag: `sudo /bin/bash -s`

Comment: Can you please let me know the exact full command structure that you are suggesting? I have tried many and nothing has worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sudo /bin/bash -s << EOF
scp file1 root@server_2:file2;
EOF
```